# How to make a condition to add/remove data param in Vue?

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, frontend

*e.g.*:

```xml
<div :data-some="someData ? okay : bad" 
     :data-someother="someOtherData ? okay : bad">
</div>
```

I want not to specify any `data-params` if there's "bad" in the result.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could compose your attributes as an object in a computed property:

```
computed: {
  attributes() {
    let attributes = {};
    if (this.someData) {
      attributes['data-some'] = this.someData;
    }
    if (this.someOtherData) {
      attributes['data-someother'] = this.someOtherData;
    }
    return attributes;
  }
}
```

And then bind those attributes to the div by passing the object to the `v-bind` directive:

```
<div v-bind="attributes"></div>
```

This way, if the data for a data-param doesn't exist, that data-param attribute won't be added to the `attributes` object, and won't be bound to the div.

Comment: note that this directive using in v-for template not static data

Comment: Then please include all relevant code in your question